On the non-existence of a boundedly complete basic sequence
Is there a Banach space X with the property that neither X nor its dual X' has a boundedly complete basic sequence?

Jog my memory: Is there known to exist a space $X$ such that its dual $X^$ does not contain a boundedly complete basic sequence? If so, $X^$ must be HI, but $X^*$ being HI is not sufficient.

@Bill Johnson: Must be HI or it does not contain an unconditional basic sequence? i.e. it is HI saturated?

I think that for $X$ separable such that $X^$ does not contain boundedly complete basic sequence then $X^$ is non separable. In my view this can be proved with the use of Ramsey theory. I mean either the classical infinite Ramsey Theory or Gowers Dichotomy.

Thank you both for your help. The property I'm trying to use is that either X or X* has a boundedly complete basic sequence, and I was wondering how general it is. I couldn't find any examples that didn't have that property.

@C Stuart: This is an interesting question. I believe that it has a negative answer. The candidate space is related to Gowers tree space and it is not explained in a mathoverflow answer.I can give you some more details if you send me an email.

Of course you are right, @SArgyros: $X^$ must be HI saturated. Also, you are right that "for  separable such that ∗ does not contain boundedly complete basic sequence then ∗ is non separable.' This is contained in my old paper with Rosenthal, "On weak$^$ basic sequences...". The proof does not use Ramsey Theory or Gowers Dichotomy.

@Bill Johnson:I was suspected that there exists an alternative approach of the non separability  of $X^* $ and I was expecting something from you.

I think that Gowers Dichotomy yields the following.If
is a Banach space with a basis $()$
then either it has a block basic sequence $()$
which is boundedly complete or it has a block basic sequence $()$
such that if $D$ denotes  $N$ with the dyadic tree order
then for every $s$
finite initial segment of $$ we have
$|\sum_{a\in s} y_a| \le 1$. The second alternative reminds the basis of the dual of James tree space.
.

In the above the sequence $(y_n)_n$ satisfies the property that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\epsilon \le |y_n| \le 1$.
